# CSV remove a row of data when column has value 0 using PHP

Tags: php, csv, row

I'm writing a cron php script to clean up a csv file before importing into a website db. Each row has a Quantity_Available field. My intention is to not write the rows with Quantity_Available == "0" to reduce the size of the file (14,000 records).

I'm comfortable with opening the existing file and writing it to a new file. Just not sure of the code for checking that field and skipping that line if it has that value.

Start Array:
Item, Quantity_Available, Color

Car,3,Blue

Horse,0,Brown

Motorcycle,2,Black

Expected result:

Car,3,Blue

Motorcycle,2,Black

I've don a good deal of searching here and haven't found this specific instance.

Comment: Post your code so people can help you

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you need to do is remove lines that have a quantity of zero and you have command line access, I suggest using `grep -v ',0,' file.csv` instead of writing PHP